# Como mudar a posição do botão bitmap?

Tags: python, wxwidgets

Inseri um botão com uma imagem no meu menu. Porém não consigo mudar sua posição. Como faço pra mudar de posição? pois preciso inserir mais 2 botões e organiza-los.Estou utilizando a biblioteca wx do python.

imagem do menu: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import wx.lib.buttons


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    title = "SEA - SunPy Environment Application"
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=self.title, size=(800, 600))
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.createMainPanel()
        self.createMainMenu()


    def createMainPanel(self, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        panel = wx.Panel(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=(0, 0), size=self.GetSize())
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('GRAY')

        bmp = wx.Bitmap("logo.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        button = wx.BitmapButton(panel,id=wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=bmp, size=(bmp.GetWidth()+10, bmp.GetHeight()+10))

        self.Centre()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bitmap, 60, 20)

    def onQuit(self, event):
        self.Close()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.mainScreen = Frame()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.mainScreen)
        self.mainScreen.Show()

        return True  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Como você gostaria de posicioná-los ?

Comment: @MagicHat esse botão eu gostaria de posicionar na parte de cima, ao centro. Os outros dois, mais abaixo, um ao lado do outro, como se formasse um triângulo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionei o atributo pos=(300,0) e funcionou.

button = wx.BitmapButton(panel,id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=(300,0), bitmap=bmp, size=(bmp.GetWidth()+10, bmp.GetHeight()+10))

Comment: Daqui um tempo poderá aceitar a resposta.